# Error en la ejecucion de clase MAIN

Tags: java, double, diseño-de-clases, java-util-scanner

```
package java01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Code_anonying{

       public static void main (String[] args){

           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.println("Digite el dato double: ");
           double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("Su numero es: " + num1);



       }
}
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
        at java01.Code_anonying.main(Code_anonying.java:12)

  \AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:

   \AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\10.0\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: Ese código compila perfectamente. Me parece que el problema está en el valor que introduces por consola que no se corresponde con un `double`.

Comment: por ejemplo 4.2 o algún carácter con punto decimal, me aparece ese error

Comment: Yo acabo de probar y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Has probado `4,2` en vez de `4.2`? Puede que haya un problema con el `Locale`.

Comment: gracias he encontrado el problema, era el punto quien me daba el error. muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si bien tu código no está mal, este error se genera al ingresar un valor que no corresponde a `double` para java por esto te doy algunas soluciones que según tu caso podrás aplicar.

En caso general, y el que yo recomendaría,
usar `Try` `Catch`, manejando la excepción

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite el dato double: ");
    try {
        double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Su numero es: " + num1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error de digitación ");
    }
```

En caso de tratarse de un error de formato, es decir, al ingresar el número, se ingresa con una coma `,` o un punto `.`, que dependiendo del idioma de tu máquina puede generar error con uno o el otro.

Cambiar el idioma en tiempo de ejecución y así el formato

```
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Locale;

    ...
    código
    ...

    Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");
    NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getInstance(spanish);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite el dato double: ");
    double num1 = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Su numero es: " + num1);
    System.out.println("Error de digitación ");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! lo tendre en cuenta.